# Read and Write Java Properties without unicode escapes

Tags: java, properties, store

this question has probably been asked and answered 100 times but unfortunately I have not found anything suitable for my issue.

The following situation: I have the problem that when I read properties to change them and then write them again, all special characters are unicode escaped.

for example ":" becomes "\:" or
Descripción becomes Descripci\u00F3n

Is there a way to change the store method so that the special characters are not escaped?

Thanks a lot

That's my code to write the properties:

```
  private static void writeUpdatedPropertiesFile(Properties newProperties, File sourceAndDestinationFile) {
    sourceAndDestinationFile.delete();
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(sourceAndDestinationFile)) {
      newProperties.store(out, null);
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you intend to achieve with that. The `load()` and `store()`-method work well together and properly deal with any encoding issues. While you definitely can write your own methods to load and store the data it most likely will only add lots and lots of encoding problems. Do you want to use the file for a different purpose than your java program? If so, which?

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay. 

It still works without any problems if the special characters are escaped but "The special characters should not be changed!" Is the statement I got so I would like to find a way to write the properties without big sources of error and not escaping the special characters

A lot of work for little benefit... but I have to do what the boss wants..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with a custom writer method:

```
    private static void writeProperties(Properties properties, File destinationFile) {

    try (final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(destinationFile), "Cp1252"))) {
      for (final Object o : properties.entrySet()) {
        final String keyValue = o.toString();
        writer.write(keyValue + "\r\n");
      }
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [store(Writer)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#store(java.io.Writer,java.lang.String)) instead of store(OutputStream).  You can construct an OutputStreamWriter with any charset you wish:

```
try (Writer out = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(sourceAndDestinationFile),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

    newProperties.store(out, null);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Of course, it is your responsibility to know that the file is a UTF-8 file, and to read it using load(Reader) instead of using an InputStream:

```
try (Reader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(sourceAndDestinationFile),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

    properties.load(in);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
}
```